# Android bug - Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-fragments, runtime-error

I am attempting to implement a to-do list using listview and listview adapter but have run into several runtime exceptions that I can't overcome. Logcat says that I am trying to invoke findViewById on a null object reference (line 24 = private Spinner spinner_priority;). However, the id for the spinner is spinnerPriority and findViewById(R.id.spinnerPriority) is invoked correctly.

I haven't changed the default ToDoActivity.java implementation except for extending ToDoActivity from FragmentActivity instead of AppCombatActivity and importing android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity instead of android.app.FragmentActivity.

Any insights as to why the app is crashing?

Logcat:

```
08-27 00:45:58.209  11873-11873/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ttse.final_tse, PID: 11873
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ttse.final_tse/com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivity.onCreate(ToDoActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivityFragment.<init>(ToDoActivityFragment.java:24)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:421)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:396)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2162)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivity.onCreate(ToDoActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

ToDoActivity.java

```
package com.ttse.final_tse;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ToDoActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_to_do, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_to_do.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivityFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_to_do"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

ToDoActivityFragment.java

```
package com.ttse.final_tse;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ToDoActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Task> list_tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    private ArrayAdapter<Task> list_adapter = null;
    private final EditText editText_title = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    private Spinner spinner_priority;
    private Button button_datepicker;
    private final TextView textView_date = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    private EditText editText_shortDescr;
    private Button button_save;

    public ToDoActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // To-Do ListView
        ListView list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        list_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_tasks);
        list.setAdapter(list_adapter);

        // Priority Spinner
        spinner_priority = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerPriority);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_priority.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);

        spinner_priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        // Datepicker Button
        button_datepicker = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonDatepicker);
        button_datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });

        // Short Description EditText
        editText_shortDescr = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextShortDescr);

        // Save Button
        button_save = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText_title.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(textView_date.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please set to-do title and due date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                onSave();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment date_picker = new DatePickerFragment();
        // show datepicker fragment on screen
        date_picker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void onSave() {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setTitle(editText_title.getText().toString());
        task.setPriority(spinner_priority.getSelectedItem().toString());
        task.setDueDate(textView_date.getText().toString());
        task.setShortDescr(editText_shortDescr.getText().toString());
        list_adapter.add(task);
        list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

fragment_to_do.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".ToDoActivityFragment">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewToDo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">

    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="7">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title..."/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Priority Level:"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerPriority"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDatepicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/pick_date"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextShortDescr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Short description..."
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_save"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
package com.ttse.final_tse;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        TextView textView_date = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        textView_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(month + 1).append("/").append(day).append("/")
                .append(year));
    }
}
```

Task.java

```
package com.ttse.final_tse;

public class Task {
    private String mTitle;
    private String mDueDate;
    private String mPriority;
    private String mShortDescr;

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getDueDate() {
        return mDueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(String dueDate) {
        mDueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return mPriority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        mPriority = priority;
    }

    public String getShortDescr() {
        return mShortDescr;
    }

    public void setShortDescr(String shortDescr) {
        mShortDescr = shortDescr;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this one exists com.ttse.final_tse/com.ttse.final_tse.ToDoActivity

Comment: Yes it exists under com.ttse.final_tse/ToDoActivity.java

Comment: replace getactivity().findViewById to getView().findViewById.

Answer (score 1):

update your code like this

```
private EditText editText_title ;
private TextView textView_date ;
```

initialize in onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // To-Do ListView
    editText_title =        (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    textView_date = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
```

Comment: Yep spotted that earlier too; bad idea to initialize widgets outside of onAcitivityCreated(). Thanks!